# graphviz dot: have two clusters with nodes in between

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the following graph

```
digraph {
    subgraph cluster_party1 {
        do_some_stuff
        and_some_stuff
        and_other_stuff

        do_some_stuff -> and_some_stuff -> and_other_stuff
    }

    subgraph cluster_party2 {
        do_that
        then_do_that
        and_this

        do_that -> then_do_that -> and_this
    }
}
```

[image: two clusters]

Now i want to add nodes in between these clusters and connect them using edges:

```
digraph {
    subgraph cluster_party1 {
        do_some_stuff
        and_some_stuff
        and_other_stuff

        do_some_stuff -> and_some_stuff -> and_other_stuff
    }

    with_this
    and_that
    using_this

    subgraph cluster_party2 {
        do_that
        then_do_that
        and_this

        do_that -> then_do_that -> and_this
    }

    do_some_stuff -> with_this -> do_that
    then_do_that -> and_that -> and_some_stuff
    and_other_stuff -> using_this -> and_this
}
```

[image: clusters with scattered nodes]

But that's not quite the result I expected. I want the nodes in between to be on the same height as the connected nodes: Let's try to rank them:

```
digraph {
    subgraph cluster_party1 {
        do_some_stuff
        and_some_stuff
        and_other_stuff

        do_some_stuff -> and_some_stuff -> and_other_stuff
    }

    with_this
    and_that
    using_this

    subgraph cluster_party2 {
        do_that
        then_do_that
        and_this

        do_that -> then_do_that -> and_this
    }

    {rank=same; rankdir=LR; do_some_stuff -> with_this -> do_that}
    {rank=same; then_do_that -> and_that -> and_some_stuff}
    {rank=same; and_other_stuff -> using_this -> and_this}
}
```

[image: clusters disappeared]

Well, they are on the same height, but the clusters disappeared and the middle row is in the wrong order. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot layout engine has a mind of its own :-)

```
digraph {

    subgraph cluster_party1 {
        do_some_stuff
        and_some_stuff
        and_other_stuff

        do_some_stuff -> and_some_stuff -> and_other_stuff
    }

    with_this
    and_that
    using_this

    subgraph cluster_party2 {
        do_that
        then_do_that
        and_this

        do_that -> then_do_that -> and_this
    }
    with_this -> and_that -> using_this [style=invis]

    do_some_stuff -> with_this -> do_that [constraint=false]
    then_do_that -> and_that -> and_some_stuff [constraint=false]
    and_other_stuff -> using_this -> and_this [constraint=false]
}
```

gives

[image]

the alternative solution is

```
digraph { rankdir = LR

    subgraph cluster_party1 {
        do_some_stuff
        and_some_stuff
        and_other_stuff
        { rank=same do_some_stuff -> and_some_stuff -> and_other_stuff }
    }

    with_this
    and_that
    using_this

    subgraph cluster_party2 {
        do_that
        then_do_that
        and_this

        { rank=same do_that -> then_do_that -> and_this }
    }

    do_some_stuff -> with_this -> do_that
    and_some_stuff -> and_that -> then_do_that [dir=back]
    and_other_stuff -> using_this -> and_this

    { rank=same with_this -> and_that -> using_this [style=invis] }
}
```

and gives

[image]

Comment: `style=invis` and `dir=back` are actually really useful, thank you!